# GROUP_CONCAT from multiple subqueries?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I can't seem to figure this out for the life of me :x

I have two tables..

- 1 = Tag Links
- 2 = Tag Data

When I query for a profile, each profile can have multiple entries in the tag links table.
Once I retrieve the tag links, I want to get the tag text from the tag data table.

I can do this with:
`SELECT * FROM platform.tagWords WHERE tagId IN (SELECT tagId FROM platform.user
sProfilesTags WHERE userId = 1001)`

But it goes through each tag (around 50,000) and then checks if it is assigned to the user so that isn't exactly a solution as each query takes 5-8 seconds.

Is there a way to reverse this?

Any tips or advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

*update

So I'm trying to give this a stab with a join, but I'm stuck there too :P

```
SELECT                                                                          

  GROUP_CONCAT(tagWords.tagWord SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags,                        
  usersProfiles.*                                                                

FROM platform.users u                                                          

INNER JOIN platform.usersProfilesTags ON usersProfilesTags.userId = u.userId   
INNER JOIN platform.usersProfiles ON usersProfiles.userId = u.userId           
INNER JOIN platform.tagWords ON tagWords.tagId = usersProfilesTags.tagId       

WHERE u.userName = 'mattstest'
```

Comment: You mention profile, but the table is Tag Data?

Comment: Yes, the other (originating table) is usersProfiles where I get the userId to find the tags that are linked from the tag links table.

Comment: What's the table schema (the `CREATE` statements for the tables)? What about the result of the join statement isn't what you desire?

Answer (score -1):

Your first query looks fine.  If it's taking 5-8 seconds, then you are probably missing an index on `usersProfilesTags(userId)`.

Trying to do this in one query is more difficult and probably slower than doing two separate queries: one query to get the profile, and another query to get the tags.  Generally, MySQL works best when you run multiple simple queries rather than one big complicated query.  Subqueries are a relatively recent feature and often perform poorly.

Also note that you are missing a `GROUP BY` for the `GROUP_CONCAT()` query.  You would need to list every column in `userProfiles` in the `GROUP BY` list.

Comment: This is bad advice. Do not try to break up queries into multiple smaller ones, do the opposite. Subquery support was added 8 years ago and does not have any innate performance problem. The more queries you issue, the more connection and communication overhead there is, the more disk IO is wasted retrieving rows you wouldn't need if the queries were combined, and the more memory you waste buffering results between programs that you're going to throw out.

Comment: I've seen many cases where MySQL creates a temporary table (without indexes) for the subquery result, which results in a slow nested-loops join.  Other times it badly merges the outer query with the inner query and runs the inner query for every row in the outer query.  Read the MySQL manual section "Optimizing Subqueries" to get an idea of how limited the optimizer is for subqueries.

Comment: I think I've got it :)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tagWord SEPARATOR ',') FROM (SELECT                   

  u.*,                                                                          
  tagWords.tagWord                                                              

FROM platform.usersProfilesTags as u                                           

INNER JOIN platform.tagWords ON tagWords.tagId = u.tagId                       

WHERE userId = 1001) as tags

Comment: Understand that I'm NOT saying to pull all the data out and process it on the client.  This is almost always a bad idea.  In thomas' case, he logically has two result sets: the profile set and the tag set.  Using two simple, fast queries to retrieve them is better than trying to cram them together in the database.